# How to display relative path while using ctag in vim

Tags: vim, ctags

I have a tags/cscope-file generated of the Linux Kernel with "make tags cscope".

Now, when I do:

```
vim -t tcp_ack
```

it shows:

```
Cscope tag: tcp_ack
   #   line  filename / context / line
   1    678  /home/christoph/workspace/linux/mptcp/drivers/net/ethernet/neterion/s2io.h <<tcp_ack>>
             __be32 tcp_ack;
   2     56  /home/christoph/workspace/linux/mptcp/include/linux/inet_lro.h <<tcp_ack>>
             __be32 tcp_ack;
   3   3292  /home/christoph/workspace/linux/mptcp/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c <<tcp_ack>>
             static int tcp_ack(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb, int flag)
Type number and <Enter> (empty cancels):
```

As you can see, it displays the whole path to the file. However, I would like it to show only the relative path to the file. Something like:

```
Cscope tag: tcp_ack
   #   line  filename / context / line
   1    678  drivers/net/ethernet/neterion/s2io.h <<tcp_ack>>
             __be32 tcp_ack;
   2     56  include/linux/inet_lro.h <<tcp_ack>>
             __be32 tcp_ack;
   3   3292  net/ipv4/tcp_input.c <<tcp_ack>>
             static int tcp_ack(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb, int flag)
Type number and <Enter> (empty cancels):
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I generated my tags-file with:
make O=../build_dir tags
That way it will include the absolute path instead of the relative path.
So, when generating the tags-file with "make tags" it works with relative file-names.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a display issue in the sense that Vim displays the path as it is recorded by the indexer.

If you want relative filenames in your `tags` file (and thus in Vim's list), you must explicitely tell ctags to do so by passing it the `--tag-relative=yes` option.

As far as I know, cscope uses relative paths by default.